# Solving for the derivative of this implicit function

Tags: calculus

I have $x$ implicitly given by

$$ x + f(x) = y $$

and I want to solve for $\frac{d x}{d y}$. How should I approach this? I know that

$$d(x+f(x))/dy = 1\\
d(x+f(x))/dx = 1 + f'(x)
$$

but I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differentiate both sides using the Chain Rule: $ \dfrac{dx}{dy} + f'(x)\dfrac{dx}{dy} = 1 \to \dfrac{dx}{dy} = \dfrac{1}{1+f'(x)}$